# How to move class functions outside of class and still use the this keyword in React?

Tags: reactjs

In react I have code like this

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
 function_name() {
   this.setState({blah: 'bleh'})
  }
 this.function_name()
}
```

but I really want to have it work like this

```
function_name() {
 this.setState({blah: 'bleh'})
}

export class Foo extends React.Component {
 this.function_name()
}
```

are there any ways to get this kind of thing to work? Basically I want the functions outside the class to reduce indentation. The problem is I'm getting `function_name is not a function`.

Comment: I really hate unnecessary indentation too in most cases, but unless the class is *huge* (in which case it should probably be refactored anyway), I think the indentation of methods inside a `class` is just fine. It's good for code organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to the prototype after declaring/exporting the class:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
  this.function_name()
}
Foo.prototype.function_name = function() {
  this.setState({blah: 'bleh'})
};
```